# react add new row with the new incoming data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I have been trying this for a long time and it's driving me crazy. 
I have an app that receives orders (data) from sockets using socket io. 
I get the data and update the state in my app.js
I have my app. js like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { subscribeToTimer } from './api';
import Board from './components/Board';
import Stream from './components/orderStream';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    subscribeToTimer((err, Order) => this.setState({ 
      Order 
    }));
  }
  state = {
    Order: 'no orders yet'
  };
  render() {
    console.log('STATE',this.state)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Stream
          OrderName = {this.state.Order.name}
          OrderEvent = {this.state.Order.event_name}
        />
        <Board 
         Order = {this.state.Order}
        />

      </div>  
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

now, in my board I would like it to create a new row (card) every time the new data comes in.
All i managed it to do is to display the row but re render it with the new data.
I would like my table to be populated as the orders come in.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Card from '../components/Card'


class Board extends Component {


    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.renderTableRows= this.renderTableRows.bind(this);

      this.state = {
      }

    }

    renderTableRows(order){
      return(
        <Card
          ID = {order.id}
          Name ={order.name}
          Status ={order.event_name}
          Time = {order.sent_at_second}
          Destination ={order.destination}
        />
      );
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="main-board flex-grid">
          <div id='resp-table'>
            <div id='resp-table-header'>
              <div className='table-header-cell order-ID'>
                Order ID
              </div>
              <div className='table-header-cell order-name'>
                Order Name
              </div>
              <div className='table-header-cell order-status'>
                Status
              </div>
              <div className='table-header-cell order-time'>
                Time
              </div>
              <div className='table-header-cell order-destination'>
                Destination
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id='resp-table-body'>
              {this.renderTableRows(this.props.Order)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
    };
}

export default Board;
```

this is the card component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Card extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    // console.log("this",this.props);
      return <div className="resp-table-row">
        <div className='table-body-cell'>
            {this.props.ID}
          </div>
          <div className='table-body-cell'>
            {this.props.Name}
          </div>
          <div className='table-body-cell'>
            {this.props.Status}
          </div>
          <div className='table-body-cell'>
           {this.props.Time}
          </div>
          <div className='table-body-cell'>
            {this.props.Destination}
          </div>
      </div>
    }
}

export default Card;
```

can anyone offer some insight please?

Comment: Will the `order` in state have one order at a time? If so you need to find a way to save the orders in an array with all the table rows. Then map over them to create the table rows

Comment: no, only one order at a time.

Comment: So you said "I would like it to create a new row (card) every time the new data comes in. ... I would like my table to be populated as the orders come in." So you want to display all orders at a time in the same table?

Comment: Do you use anything to help with state management like React's useContext hook, or Redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React creates the view from the modal (the data). In your case you wish the view to include all received orders. To do so, you need to save the orders in an array in the state (in the `App` component), and supply them to the component that renders the view (`Board`). The needs `Board` needs to iterate the array, and generate a list of `Card` components.

The `App` component should store all received orders in an array:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    subscribeToTimer((err, Order) => this.setState(state => ({ 
      Order: [...state.Order, order] // add the Order to the previous state.Order
    })));
  }
  state = {
    Order: [] // init order with an empty array
  };
  render() {
    const { Order } = this.state;
    const { name, event_name } = Order[order.length - 1] || {}; // get the names from the laster order - or undefined if none
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Stream
          OrderName = {name}
          OrderEvent = {event_name}
        />
        <Board 
         Order = {this.state.Order}
        />

      </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

And the `Board` component should render the entire array of table boards whenever one is added:

```
renderTableRows(order){
  return order.map(order => (
    <Card
      key = {order.id}
      ID = {order.id}
      Name ={order.name}
      Status ={order.event_name}
      Time = {order.sent_at_second}
      Destination ={order.destination}
    />
  ));
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.